# Why is my date not getting formatted as per the dateformat

Tags: java

I want to save a date in a particular format, below is my code:

Class level:

```
Date timestampbackup;
```

Local method level:

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String fechaStr = (new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString();  

    System.out.println("fechaStr "+fechaStr.toString());

    timestampbackup = format.parse(fechaStr);

    System.out.println("timestamp "+timestampbackup.toString());
```

and here is the output:

```
        fechaStr 2015-01-23 17:54:25.465
        timestamp Fri Jan 23 17:54:25 GMT+05:30 2015
```

What is possibly wrong here?

Comment: Where do you think yo use `SimpleDateFormat#format()`?

Comment: `timestampbackup = format.parse(fechaStr);` ??

Comment: Dont do this: new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString()

Comment: `parse` <> `format`, see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Ah I will have to use format.format!!

Comment: You're calling toString on a timestamp, then creating a Date from the resulting String and calling toString on it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please ignore the rough code I was just experimenting and will improve once I get the result :)

Comment: @Stefan What do you suggest me to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
String fechaStr = (new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString();
```

Works regardless of the format you created. `Timestamp` is from the `java.sql` package, and therefore its `toString()` method is returning the date in the SQL standard format.

You shouldn't be doing this to convert the date to this string format. This class should be used for setting time stamps in the database, not for date formatting. It may cause problems with the time zone if you use it.

Then you use

```
timestampbackup = format.parse(fechaStr);
```

Which takes the date string that you created and parses it, and puts it in the `timestampbackup` object. Now, your `timestampbackup` is a `java.util.Date`, not a `java.sql.Date`, which is good, but it means its `toString()` method works according to the default format for your locale.

Parsing created a date object that stores the information internally as time elapsed since a given start date. So parsing using the format is not going to affect the way the date is displayed. Any format information is lost.

So you should use `format.format(timestampbackup)` rather than `timestampbackup.toString()` to get the string you wanted. And it doesn't matter at all what it was parsed from.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did some mistakes formatting and then using the toString().. The following code is working well for me. Just use ft.format() to get a time-formatted string back.

```
    Date dNow = new Date( );
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(ft.format(dNow));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: 
`format.format(<your date>)`